# Select records from two tables if atleast 4 records in second table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables and i want to fetch data based on below condition:

- Table1 has multiple product records.
- Table2 contains various Size option for products and can not have more or less than 4 rows.

> Now, i want to fetch those products which do not have entry or do not have exact 4 entries.

Table Structure is as below:

**Table1**

```
id   name  color  price   instock
----------------------------------
 1   rice   white  1200    1
 2   shoe   brown  2500    1
 3   belt   red    5200    1
```

**Table2**

```
  id   size   pid
 -----------------
  1     5     1
  2     10    1
  3     4     1 
  4     15    1
  5     7     2
```

Now Query shall fetch product with ID 2 and 3 as they have records less than 4 and no record resp.

I was using below query to fetch products which have no records in `Table2`

```
SELECT p.* FROM `Table1` p LEFT JOIN `Table2` t ON p.id = t.pid  WHERE 
t.pid IS NULL
```

Comment: So, you don't want data which is having less than 4 record in table 2 or what ?

Comment: No. I want data which has less than 4 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.color, p.price, p.instock, count(t.*) 
FROM `Table1` p 
LEFT JOIN `Table2` t 
ON p.id = t.pid  
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.color, p.price, p.instock
HAVING count(t.*) < 4
```

Comment: why u have added group by??

Comment: is it necessary to select all columns? can't i get only required columns

Comment: you can just list the required columns.  But make sure the list is the same in the SELECT as it is in the GROUP BY

Comment: this would also work: SELECT p.id, p.name, p.color, p.price, count(t.*) 
FROM `Table1` p 
LEFT JOIN `Table2` t 
ON p.id = t.pid  
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.color, p.price
HAVING count(t.*) < 4

Comment: I have an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM `Table1` p LEFT JOIN `Table2` t ON p.id = t.pid GROUP BY p.' at line 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102274/discussion-between-jeff-and-gags).

Comment: sorry for the noise.  count(t.*) should have been count(*)